# Acer VN7-591G, WiFi and Bluetooth not working

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 14.10, acer, atheros

On my Acer VN7-591G I just bought the wifi and Bluetooth (both on the same chip) are not currently working (using Ubuntu 14.10).

As stated by a sticker on the bottom of the notebook:
"This device contains WLAN-Bluetooth module QCNFA344", but I can't find any information about this module anywhere on the net. The wifi module isn't shown with ifconfig, while the bluetooth seems to be recognized (bluetooth symbol is shown in upper right corner next to clock), but doesn't find any devices.

Any help would really be appreciated.

[edit:]

lspci output:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e08e]
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04f2:b474 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0489:e092 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of hciconfig --all: (only the internal card)

```
hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:5A:AD  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1229 acl:0 sco:0 events:51 errors:0
    TX bytes:1506 acl:0 sco:0 commands:51 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ubuntu-0'
    Class: 0x6c0100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x25a
    Manufacturer: Qualcomm (29)
```

the device is being shown as hci1, as i plugged in another bt-dongle via usb

Comment: Open a terminal window and post the results of the following `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` `lsusb`

Comment: In addition please attach the results of `hciconfig --all` I suspect it is an Atheros AR3012 device that is not supported in the latest kernel but I might be able to help

Comment: Just one more `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep -iA30 Port=07`

Comment: `sudo cat /sys/kernel....` (copy / paste) didn't output anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for your device. I suggest you add to the existing bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

Answer (score 1):

Download https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bx1gtf2oxwnv588/AADUBfza3w3e1YJKCufqeqZea?dl=0

```
cd Downloads
sudo modprobe -r ath3k
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko.bak
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
sudo cp ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo modprobe ath3k
```

You may get an error with `sudo modprobe -r ath3k` as I doubt it loaded but this should get bluetooth running

Comment: sadly after trying this, the builtin bluetooth module isn't even shown with hciconfig anymore - even after reboot

Comment: Then you may have another issue going on `dmesg | grep firmware` please

Comment: yes, it seems so - using dmesg shows `[ 1696.302321] usb 3-10: Direct firmware load failed with error -2`

Comment: Try this `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` then reboot, open terminal enter `sudo modprobe ath3k` and see if bluetooth works

Comment: Still the same results as before (tried with both - original and your .ko files) - thank you very much for your help till now. Hope you didn't run out of ideas yet...

Comment: See what `dmesg | grep ar3k` might dig up.  It appears that it is looking for a firmware file that is not part of linux yet.  Normally some files for these are located in /lib/firmware/ar3k

Comment: `dmesg | grep ar3k` tells me: `[ 1527.814863] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x00000200.dfu`

Comment: Unfortunately the needed dfu file can not be found on the internet, so I cannot go any further.  I think you should add yourself to the bug and get a wifi card like http://www.amazon.com/7260-IEEE-802-11ac-Bluetooth-4-0/dp/B00DMNSVQM if it matches the shape of your current chip.  The intel 7260 wifi and bluetooth is supported by Linux, I have 2 different versions with a connection that is different than the link.

Comment: Well, that's actually a little sad - but I didn't really await to get that far anyways.
Do you think you could maybe provide the changes you've done to the *.ko files' sources, so I can add them to the bug report mentioned by chili555?
Although I know this is surely absolutely pointless, I'll anyhow try to get Qualcomm contacted for the dfu file.

You don't maybe happen to have ideas for the WLan Part of the chip? Guess we'd end up with another required firmware file...

Comment: No ideas on the wifi part as it would likely be supported by the developers that work on the ath10k module.  I sent an email to the ath9k devs about the firmware files, hopefully linux can get rights to distribute them.  Here is where you can download the files before they were compiled https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n1gza7phg8yht8d/AACAzCnlQf8NhpbaXwHN8xhMa?dl=0

Comment: This is very experimental and I dont know if it might cause damage but it might work `sudo cp /lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu /lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x00000200.dfu` and reboot and check `dmesg | grep ramp`

Comment: nice idea, but didn't do anything positive. no idea what the "ramp" should do (did output sth about a trampoline) regular dmesg told me `[20302.626899] Bluetooth: Patch file version did not match with firmware` and `[20302.626904] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed`. Anyways thank you so very much for your efforts. let's see, if i might get any response from qualcomm at all....

Comment: Just checking on a good guess or so I thought as I found a bug report that was looking for the same AthrBT_0x00000200.dfu file but had the same lsusb device ID as my bluetooth, so I hoped that renaming it might work.  I sent an email to the kernel developers about support for bluetooth and the firmware and the response was some time in the future.  I hope you hear good news from qualcomm